# Using -- Can a mysql user own tables?

Tags: mysql

A user can create tables owned by them in Oracle.
Can this be done using MySQL?

Answer (score 1):

There is no "ownership", only permission to read/write/drop/etc.  However, it is possible to have conventions of how permissions are `GRANTed` that sells a lot like "ownership".

Admin (typically 'root'):

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO root@...
```

"Owners":

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON Leslie_database.* TO Leslie@...
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON Dana_database.* TO Dana@...
```

That lets Leslie do everything with `Leslie_database`, but he/she cannot touch `Data_database`.

Note that the syntax `schema.DBO.tablename` does not exist in MySQL, only `dbname.tablename`.

Close enough to "ownership"?

`GRANTs` can also be done at the "table" level, and even the "column".

You *could* let Leslie "see" `Dana_database`:

```
GRANT SELECT ON Dana_database.* TO Leslie@...
```

Answer (score 0):

What you sure can do is grand per table permission to a single user, which is possibly what you want to achieve:

For instance, if the user already exists:

```
GRANT SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE ON dbname.tablename TO 'username'@'localhost';
```

If the user account hasn't been created yet you can set it up at the same time as its permissions:

```
GRANT SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE ON dbname.tablename TO 'username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

Cheers,

Comment: When a user creates tables, are those tables owned by that user, or you can only grant the permissions to the user? I am talking about ownership not grants